# How to improve signal quality in SDR-to-SDR TX/RX test?

Tags: gnuradio

I'm have a GNURadio flowgraph with 2 SDR devices directly connected with an SMA cable. It sort of works, but I'm wondering if I can improve signal quality.

[image]

On the TX side, clean signal is generated at 10KHz and 50KHz. I then send it through ADALM-PLUTO SDR with LO set to 1GHz as a carrier.

[image]

On the RX side, I use RTL-SDR with LO set to 999MHz, 1MHz off from TX carrier to eliminate DC offset. However, at this point, signal quality isn't that good:

[image]

I can see the signal at 1MHz mark, but overall, this looks quite noisy to me. Considering that this is over a direct SMA cable connection, I was expecting cleaner result with more distinct signal peaks.

I've been tweaking PlutoSDR TX attenuation and RTL-SDR gain settings, but no parameter configuration seems to improve this.

So my questions are:

1. Is this a sane result from your experience?
2. If not, then how can I isolate/identify an issue?
   For example, what can I do to tell if this is an issue of TX side or RX side?
3. What can be the cause of signal degradation in this cable-connected case?

=== Update and resolution ===
Thanks to @Marcus Müller, his advice led me to find that I was wrong on TX attenuator configuration. After fixing it, I get additional 20dB which significantly improved signal quality as shown below:

[image]

Comment: you might be overdriving your receiver. test with only one tone, and look at the time domain (Qt time sink) and verify it doesn't look like a compressed sine. If it does, reduce gain on both TX and RX.

Comment: Also, I don't see any significant effect of your low pass filter there, so try without that, first. This is really an exercise in debugging: try the simplest thing to verify it works, and then make it more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @MarcusMüller ! You were spot on - I switched to single-tone generation and then noticed I had wrong TX attenuation range configured - way lower than it can be. I updated the setup and now I get additional 20dB :-)